# How to set background gradient (shape) to a vector asset in android?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I have a home icon from vector assets clipart in android.
I want to set a gradieant to it or trnsparent it for showing the view behind of it.

**Left: I have it.**

**Right: I want it.**

[image]

Comment: By vector asset, do you mean SVG?

Comment: right click on drawable folder and new -> vector asset

Comment: Since it's an icon, probably, it doesn't have the transparent color for house.

Comment: Is there any aproch for implement the right side UI?

Comment: You can create your own SVG image with house color as transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to re-create that icon manually. You can save it to an SVG file. Additionally, you can change the fill color and apply gradient. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp) to learn how to do that.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path 
              d="M 50 50
                  m -50, 0
                  a 50,50 0 1,0 100,0
                  a 50,50 0 1,0 -100,0
                  M38,65 
                 L38,50 
                 L30,50 
                 L50,30 
                 L70,50 
                 L62,50
                 L62,65
                 L52,65
                 L52,55
                 L48,55
                 L48,65
                 L40,65
              Z" />
        </clipPath>
     </defs>
    
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

In the path, the below is for the circle:

```
M 50 50
m -50, 0
a 50,50 0 1,0 100,0
a 50,50 0 1,0 -100,0
```

and below is for the house:

```
M38,65 
L38,50 
L30,50 
L50,30 
L70,50 
L62,50
L62,65
L52,65
L52,55
L48,55
L48,65
L40,65
```

References:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57958317)
- [Link 2](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#path_C)
- [Link 3](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp)